# Counting distinct using pandas groupby not working

Tags: python, pandas, count, distinct

All I am trying to do is iterate through a DataFrame and count the number of unique values using the pandas group by. I also sorted the data frame to no avail.

I've tried 15 different methods and have read every question/response thread I can find, and I have no idea why it isn't working.

Code to create the DF:

```
#list of queries is literally a python list of queries in no specified #order

user_queries = pd.DataFrame(list_of_queries)

user_queries = user_queries.rename(index=str, columns={0: "queries"})
# I only added the int 1 because pandas refused to just count the #queries themselves
user_queries["count"] = 1
```

What it looks like before the group-by code

```
      queries  count

1234      test         1
1234      test         1  

user_queries["query_counts"] = user_queries.groupby("queries")["count"].nunique()
user_queries.head()
```

What it should look like

```
|    ,queries,count,query_counts|
|1234,test   ,1    ,2           |
```

But instead of the "2", it gives me NaNs for every value instead. I feel like I'm missing something simple, but

The last column should have the sum of the column "count" grouped by the column "queries"

Comment: Cannot reproduce NaNs with your data.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the transform method

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html

```
user_queries["query_counts"] = user_queries.groupby("queries")["count"].transform('nunique')
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I'll look into the documentation for .transform() to figure out why I was using the incorrect method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your use case:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

queries = [
    (1233, np.nan),
    (1234, 'test'),
    (1235, 'test'),
    (1236, 'foo'),
    (1237, 'bar'),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(queries, columns=['id', 'query'])
print(df.groupby('query')['id'].count())
```

outputs:

```
query
bar     1
foo     1
test    2
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you group by all the columns you will get grouped dataframes from where you can extract the length of each group.

```
grouped = user_queries.groupby(["queries","count"])
res = None
for group_name, df in grouped:
    df['query_counts'] = int(df.shape[0])
    if res==None:
        res = df.iloc[:1]
    else:
        res = pd.concat([res,df.iloc[0:1]])

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single groupby:

```
In [11]: df.groupby([df.index, "queries", "count"]).size()
Out[11]:
      queries  count
1234  test     1        2
dtype: int64

In [12]: df.groupby([df.index, "queries", "count"]).size().reset_index(name="query_count")
Out[12]:
   level_0 queries  count  query_count
0     1234    test      1            2
```

or

```
In [13]: df.groupby(["queries", "count"]).size()
Out[13]:
queries  count
test     1        2
dtype: int64

In [14]: df.groupby(["queries", "count"]).size().reset_index(name="query_count")
Out[14]:
  queries  count  query_count
0    test      1            2
```